# How to check if a string equals to "}"

Tags: java, string, equals

How to check if a string is equals to "}"?

I've tried

```
  str_.equals("\\}");
```

and

```
   str_.equals("[}]");
```

None of them seems working.

Comment: Which one is it -- "}"  or "{" ???

Comment: Slartibartfast   its "}"

Comment: What's with the backslashes? :)

Comment: is your string just "{" else use str_.contains("{")

Comment: I tried that first time. Then only i tried the above ones.

Comment: so your string contains more than just "{"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `str_.equals("{");`
or `str_.equals("}");`

We are still not sure which brace

**EDIT:** Ah now we have clarity.

Use `str_.equals("}");`

Comment: Why aren't you sure?  I'm 99% confident he's referring to `}`.

Comment: Use `"}".equals(str_);` - You won't get a NPE if `str_` is `null`.

Comment: ^ +1. @jipp What is the input ?

Answer (score 11):

Use [String#equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) like that:

```
str_.equals("}");
```

Comment: I tried that first time. But didint worked Then i tried the above ones

Comment: I prefer `"}".equals(str_)` just in case `str_` is `null` you won't get a `NPE`..

Comment: @jjpp - If it didn't work for you the first time then the chances are that the real problem is in the string you are testing.  This code is CORRECT.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - On the contrary, I prefer `str_.equals("}")` because I will get an NPE if `str_` is `null` when I'm not expecting that.  Unexpected / unanticipated `null` values are usually bugs, and it is best to *know* about bugs rather than hiding them under layers of "bandaid solutions".

Comment: @StephenC That's a good point.. But sometimes it is set to `null` on purpose to indicate something (When `""` has another meaning, so you must set it to `null`..)

Comment: If a `null` string has a specific (non-bug) meaning, then your approach makes sense ... but I wouldn't do that by default, which is what I thought you were recommending.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "}";
        System.out.println(s.equals("}"));

    }
```

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase` since when `}` has a case? :D

Comment: You're right, but I feel like you're doing two things wrong - `}` has no case, and you can do a direct `System.out.println` of the boolean statement.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun +1 from me u have detected.. s.equalsIgnoreCase("}").

Comment: @shreyansh jogi ya sometimes we simply do copy-paste and then illogical statement generate.:)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple **[Java - String equals() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm)** method buddy......

```
String val1="{", val2="}";

    if(val1.equals("{"))
    {
     System.out.println("Open Brackets");
    }
    else if(val2.equals("}"))
    {
     System.out.println("Close Brackets");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 StringName.equals("}");
```

if you want to ckeck whether some string contain '{' use

```
 StringName.contains("}");
```

EDIT : If you used

```
 str_.equals("}"); before. may be your string contains white spaces.
```

to avoid that do as follows

```
 str_.trim().equals("}");
```

Now white spaces no longer an issue.